# Importing an image in PDF format generated by R into Adobe Illustrator results in changes to the image's colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, maps

I created a map using R and wanted to edit it in Adobe Illustrator. However, I found that some countries' colors were missing when I imported the generated PDF file into Illustrator.

The first image is the one I generated in R, and the second image is after editing in AI. As you can see, the color blocks for Canada are missing.
[image]

[image]

I've tried a few methods, such as changing the view mode and rendering in RGB mode in R, but none of these solutions have resolved my issue.

**What should I do?**

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Those don't look like changes to the colours. Something is up with the fills. It looks like you have some areas which are not closed paths, and so the fill isn't working properly. If you look closely, parts of the Canadian coastline appear to be missing.

Comment: Might be easier to just find a n SVG map, and then you can colourise it in Illustrator natively. There's a similar Creative Commons Map on Wikimedia Commons [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-Equirectangular.svg)

Comment: @BillyKerr  I appreciate your advice and help!  I have already tried the SVG format, but it still isn't working. What I ended up doing was directly dragging the PDF file into Adobe Illustrator and editing the image as a hyperlink, effectively 'skipping' the issue

Answer (score 0):

this likely has to do with ICC profiles. In Illustrator at the top to go to Edit- Assign profile. check the preview box. then try clicking on different ones.

For printing we recommend either Adobe RGB 1998 or sRGB

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I've tried different ICC profiles in Illustrator. But I didn't spot any differences.

Comment: Is there a way you can share the original file?